# Когда в русском языке появилось слово «бутилированный»?

Tags: этимология

Когда в русской языке ВПЕРВЫЕ появилось слово «бутилированный»?

И еще:

"Бутылка и  бутилированный"  - это родственные слова? А почему  тогда пишутся по-разному? Или не совсем родственные, а только наполовину?

И имеют ли они  (только одно, или оба, или каждое в отдельности) отношение к английскому  слову «butter – масло»?

А также можно ли найти их и.-е (не латинский) корень, или он не существует вовсе?

Благодарю всех, кто поможет разъяснить эти вопросы.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Там не все так просто, какой-то клубок связей. Бутил - производное от "бутан", а слово "бутан" происходит от английского названия масляной кислоты — butyric acid, а там уже и английское масло недалеко - butter. И это масло вроде бы как родственно слову bottle - бутылка и русскому глаголу ботать/болтать в значении «сбивать  масло предметом в форме бутылки».

"Болтать" считают звукоподражательным словом, а латинский след "бутылки" заканчивается словом bottis - бочка.

Вот и как разобрать: где начало, где конец, что похоже на правду, а что не очень.

Просто замкнутый круг получается: бутылкой взбивали масло, потом получили маслянистый бутил, который в форме слова  "бутилированный" неожиданно вернулся к этой бутылке.

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что хим. термин *бутилированный* появился в "19 веке". Я не нашел ни одной подобной ссылки. Может, кто поищет лучше?

Comment: ИЗ НАЦКОРПУСА:
"Ввиду этого можно было предполагать, что изотрибутилен будет представлять не что иное, как дву (третично) бутилированный изобутилен или одно (третично) бутилированный изодибутилен". [А. М. Бутлеров. Теоретические и экспериментальные работы по химии (1851-1886)]

Answer (score 3):

С учетом всех полученных ответов я попробую составить определенное мнение по данному вопросу.

1) Слово "бутылка" вошло в русский язык  с начала 18 века – через польское  butelka от французского   bouteille .  Польские гласные А, О, U, Е, I произносятся как А, О, У, Э, И, отсюда твердое произношение гласного.

Почему именно тогда? К тому времени (с 1635 года)  в Росси уже существовал «стекляничный» завод, для производства "стеклянных посуд": рюмки, чарки, братины, кувшинцы, особые"потешные" кубки. Но до 1800 года стеклянные бутылки в России использовали только для аптекарских целей (вместе с аптекарскими скляницами) . Тогда же вышел указ, запрещающий ввоз стеклотары из–за границы, и бутылки стали использовать для пищевых продуктов.

2) Слово "бутилированный" (в значении «расфасованный в бутылки»)  с мягким  «И» вошло в русский язык сравнительно недавно, в конце ХХ века. Очевидно, это связано с появлением  бутилированной воды.  Заимствование могло осуществляться  через болгарский  или французский язык: в болгарском языке  бутылка – бутилка, разлитый по бутылкам - бутилирано, во французском языке: embouteillé –разлитый в бутылки.

Также я дам ссылки на некоторые дискуссии по этому вопросу:

http://www.ljpoisk.ru/archive/6185173.html

http://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/3887163.html

Грамота.ру   Вопрос 10066

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос 10066:    В печатных текстах слово "бутилированная" (вода) встречается гораздо чаще, чем "бутылированная ". Но ведь корень этого слова "бутыл", а не "бутил". "Бутилированная" вода ассоциируется с этилированным бензином. Теоретически слово "бутилированная" возможно (химики скажут, существует ли оно), но его этимология будет связана с названием химического соединения, а не с бутылкой. Как же правильно называть воду, расфасованную в бутылки?

Ответ:   Вода, расфасованная в бутылки, в речевой практике именуется, как Вы заметили, и бутилированной, и бутылированной. В академическом «Русском орфографическом словаре (под ред. В. В. Лопатина, издан в Москве в 2005 году) тем не менее представлено только слово «бутилировать и его производные (бутилированный, бутилирование). Таким образом в словаре отражен вариант, восходящий к французскому оригиналу bouteille и сохраняющий его особенности (в частности, произношение мягкого согласного звука [т’]). Это заимствование (в значении «расфасовать в бутылки») появилось в русском языке сравнительно недавно, в конце ХХ века. Этим объясняется фонетическое расхождение с родственным словом «бутылка, которое появилось в русском языке намного раньше, скорее всего через посредство польского и украинского языков, привнесших в произношение иностранного слова свои фонетические особенности (см. справку для слова «бутылка» в «Этимологическом словаре русского языка» Макса Фасмера: «с 1694 г., у Петра I; см. Христиани 47. Заимств. через укр., польск. butelka "бутылка" или прямо из франц. bouteille — то же, от ср.-лат. buticula: butis, buttis "бочка". Ср. также бутель, 1719 г., у кн. Куракина; см. Христиани, там же; Брюкнер 51. Последнее, возм., из нем. Buttel или франц. bouteille).
Если решать вопрос о выборе одного из двух вариантов, то очевидно, что предпочтение следует отдать рекомендованному словарем глаголу «бутилировать. Еще один аргумент в его пользу: профессионалы, как можно судить по примерам употребления, пользуются именно этим словом. Глагол «бутылировать обычно встречается в разговорной речи.

Comment: Е321 - это бутилированный гидрокситолуол. Таким образом, со второй половины 19 века слово "бутилированный" существует как химический термин. Естественно предположить, что оно повлияло на другое (новое) значение  слова в сочетании "бутилированная вода", которое появилось во второй половине 20 века. И вот это "химическое" слово никакого отношения к "бутылке" не имеет? Или имеет?

Comment: Нет, София, к химическому термину оно не имеет никакого отношения. Слово заимствовано из французского.    bouteille - бутылка.

Answer (score 1):

Слова появляются в языке, когда они требуются для обозначения каких-либо **новых реалий.** Так, слово «**бутылка»** было заимствовано  в Петровскую эпоху из польск. яз., где butelka < франц. bouteille, восходящего к лат. butis «бочонок, сосуд». И всегда заимствованное слово подбирает для себя **удобную фонетическую форму.**

Слово **«бутилированный»** получило широкое распространение только в XX веке, когда производство бутилированной воды приобрело промышленные масштабы. Кстати, **химический термин** существовал уже в XIX веке и оказался вполне подходящим названием для этого прилагательного, так что и выбирать долго не пришлось.

Почему **И, а не Ы?** Мне представляется совсем «простая штука» – все та же **фонетика!** Согласный Т лучше сочетался с формантом с «илировать», чем с «ылировать».

Так что нет ничего **разговорного, просторечного или диалектного** в этом русском слове, закрепленном в словаре.

Answer (score 0):

Простите, София, но Вы сейчас ерундой маетесь. Проследить происхождение термина путём анализа **заимствований** - это что-то.

В разное время и различными путями в русский язык пришли термины "бутыль"(ёмкость) и "бутилированный"(разлитый). Очевидно, что эти два термина "где-то там" имеют общее происхождение (семантическое подобие). Но **в русском языке** это - два разных слова, не имеющих между собой **никаких** связей. Отсюда - и различие в написании.

Что же касается Вашего предположения о "химическом" бутиле..

> Бутил - одновалентный радикал бутана,
> или заместитель с формулой С4Н9,
> производное бутана...

Из химии вспоминаем, что "бут-" означает наличие 4 атомов углерода, а "-ил" - наличие свободной валентной связи.

Ну и как это соотносится с термином "разлить"?

Comment: К концу 20 века появилось слово "бутилированный" - разлитый по бутылкам. С тех пор на форумах постоянно возникает вопрос: почему не "бутылированный". Я не нашла на него убедительного ответа и сделала предположение, что уже существующий химический термин мог оказать влияние на новое слово, никак не связанное с ним по значению. Потом мне захотелось узнать, откуда появился бутан (его название связано с масляной кислотой, англ.) и т.д. Мне показалась  детективной вся история, захотелось поделиться с форумом. Это и есть примерный перечень действий, которые вы вежливо назвали "ерундой маетесь".

Comment: А термины "разлить, или распределить, или ещё что сделать) здесь совершенно ни при чем, исследования касались корня БУТ: бутыль - бутилировать.

Comment: А "убедительного" ответа в рамках русского языка Вы и не найдёте. Слово - заимствованное. Причём - недавно. "пообтесаться" ещё не успело. И используется в транскрипции заимствования.

Comment: Корень "бут" (по крайней мере, в этом случае) - заимствованный. И разбираться в происхождении терминов, от него образованных, необходимо на языке источника.

Comment: Вы какой источник имеете в виду? Мне бы хотелось найти и.-е. корень, также уточнить происхождение англ. "butter" - точно ли оно связано с русским словом "ботать", или с чем связано? Здесь требуется помощь знатоков английского языка, но они, увы, не откликнулись.

Comment: Корень надо искать в латыни (butis). А, вот, всё остальное... Здесь, вообще-то русский язык обсуждают.

Comment: Если убрать форму, которую кто-то может счесть бестактной, то суть greydog подметил верно. Слова пришли в язык разными путями - и родственными не могут быть по определению. А исследованием английского масла пусть англичане занимаются.

Comment: Точно. Вот, к примеру, Черных занимался этимологией РУССКОГО языка, а зачем-то везде искал и.-е корни или о.-с. основу. И до английского butter, и до латинской butis ему почему-то всегда было дело. Чудак человек, а все остальные молодцы.

Answer (score 0):

Если  люди  привыкнут  называть  воду,  разлитую  в  бутылки,  бутилированой,  то  слово  получит  прописку  в  русском  языке.  Вернее,  уже  получило.  Не  все  люди  химики,  не  все  наслышаны   о  бутиле.  Хотя,  именно  из-за  наличия  бутила  возможно  и  такое  название  раствора  бутила.  Может  быть  путаница.  Позтому  "бутылированая  вода"  правильней.  И  абсолютно  непонятно,  почему  словарь  предпочёл   термин  бутилировать.  Надо  бы  спросить  у  В.В. Лопатина: почему ?

Comment: Здесь, скорее, язык выбрал это слово, практически "бутылированный" нигде не встречается. Словарь только фиксировал выбор.

Answer (score 0):

> Когда в русской языке ВПЕРВЫЕ появилось слово «бутилированный»?

Только на моей памяти уже лет как сорок.

> "Бутылка и бутилированный" - это родственные слова? А почему тогда пишутся по-разному? Или не совсем родственные, а только наполовину?

Вот  тут надо разобраться, что имеется в виду под родственностью. Если придерживаться того подхода, что родственность устанавливается на уровне самого языка, т.е. родственность в языках-источниках не рассматривается (такой трактовки придерживается большинство языковедов, Фасмер, например), то очевидно, что нет, поскольку в язык слова попали разными путями.

Comment: Вы считаете, что между "бутылью" и "бутилированный" нет прямой мотивации "бутыль - бутилированный"?

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте, господа, про химию. Это слово, "бутилированный", есть в разных языках. Когда-то много было болгарского вина и коньяков, и на них много лет назад так и писали:"бутилирано", в немецком варианте(попадалось и такое) писали "butilieren". Профессиональные виноделы давным давно ввели это слово в лексикон, словари только зафиксировали это. Все эти bottle, buteille и т.д. возникли от латинского buticula. Через "и". Потому и "бутилированный", что благозвучно и исторично. Зачем же голову ломать?

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, я учту его при ответе на вопрос.